# How to split everything before the hyphen and add quotes and a comma in Excel?

Tags: excel, string, split

I have a column in Excel that looks as such below.

[image]

How can I split this into another column as such

**Before/Current state**

```
60080204-S/O BEACON SUPPLY.
```

**To/Ideal State**

```
'60080204',
```

Comment: If those numbers are always 8 digits long you can take the left of each string. Here is a question though: Do you need the result to be in single quotes followed by a comma or is that a typo? If no typo, just concat these onto the result with the "&". Give it an honest attempt and update your question if you have a question that is on-topic on SO (read: not too broad). See [ask] a quesiton with a [mcve].

Comment: yeah they are all 8 digis long, and it can be single quote or double quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated before, you can simply use the `LEFT()` function for that:

```
=LEFT(A2,8)
```

If you are not sure that there will always be 8 digits, you might use `FIND()` for finding the hyphen character:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)
```

In case you have more questions, feel free to comment on this answer.

As indicated by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321042/andrew), you might add the single quote at the beginning and single quote, followed by the comma, as follows:

```
="'"&LEFT(A2,8)&"',"
```

Or, in compliance with my second proposal:

```
="'" & LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1) & "',"
```

(I've added spaces around the ampersand `&` character for readability reasons.)

Comment: Would the complete answer be `="'"&LEFT(A2,8)&"',"`?

Comment: @Andrew: you're right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.